# How to disable the swt Browser clicking sound when used in Eclipse RCP application on windows?

Tags: java, maven, internet-explorer, swt, tycho

I have embedded an swt Browser in my Eclipse RCP application. My problem is that on Windows the `setUrl()` and `dispose()` methods of the browser cause the (annoying) internet explorer navigation sound (the 'click') which is undesirable.

I found this piece of code that successfully disables the clicking sound

```
OS.CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(OS.FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS, OS.SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS, true);
```

But since this is restricted API I have trouble building the application using Maven/Tycho.

```
[ERROR] OS.CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(OS.FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS, OS.SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS, true);
[ERROR] ^^
[ERROR] OS cannot be resolved to a variable
[ERROR] 4 problems (4 errors)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:0.22.0:compile (default-compile) on project com.myapp: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)...
```

Is there a way to get Maven/Tycho to compile while using this restricted API?

Or is there another way to disable the IE browser navigation sounds on Windows?

Comment: So you need to get the bundle or fragment that contains the `OS` class onto the compile classpath. Which bundle or fragment contains that class?

Comment: oberlies, you are correct but that is easier said than done. I have posted an answer below that shows how it has to be done.

Comment: Very good post! And thank you very much for sharing your insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to crack this eventually and here's how.

Since this restrictive API lives in platform specific plugins i.e. SWT 32bit and SWT 64bit, I created two platform specific fragments to hold the code.

To get maven to compile the fragments the following line needs to be added to the 32-bit fragment in file build.properties:

```
extra.. = platform:/fragment/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86
```

and the following for the 64-bit fragment build.properties

```
extra.. = platform:/fragment/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64
```

The maven pom configuration files should also be platform specific which is done by adding the following section in the pom.xml of the 32 bit fragment

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>

            <configuration>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here's the 64-bit version.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Also do not forget to set the respective platform filter in the fragment manifest as shown here

```
Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.os=win32) (osgi.arch=x86))
Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.os=win32) (osgi.arch=x86_64))
```

We then place the silencing code in a Class in each fragment. This class should implement an interface in the host plugin. 
The host plugin defines an extension point that takes a class implementing the interface in the host plugin. The fragments then declare an extension and provides the class name in the fragment.

When the host code needs to run the silencing code it needs to check for extensions and instantiate and call the silencing code.

Example:

```
package com.mypackage;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IConfigurationElement;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IExtensionRegistry;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.ISafeRunnable;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Creatable;

import com.mypackage.ISilencer;

@Creatable
public class BrowserSilencer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BrowserSilencer.class);

    @Inject
    IExtensionRegistry exReg;

    public void silence=() {
        IConfigurationElement[] config = exReg.getConfigurationElementsFor("com.mypackage.silencer");
        try {
            for (IConfigurationElement e : config) {
                final Object o = e.createExecutableExtension("class");
                if (o instanceof ISilencer) {
                    executeExtension(o);
                }
            }
        } catch (CoreException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error finding the com.mypackage.silencer extension");
        }
    }

    private void executeExtension(final Object o) {
        ISafeRunnable runnable = new ISafeRunnable() {
            @Override
            public void handleException(Throwable e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception while attempting to silence browser");
            }

            @Override
            public void run() throws Exception {
                ((ISilencer) o).silence();
            }
        };
        SafeRunner.run(runnable);
    }
}
```

The interface in the host plugin

```
package com.mypackage;
public interface ISilencer {
   public void silence();
}
```

and an example of the code in the 64 bit plugin. The 32-bit is almost the same

```
package com.mypackage.fragment.win64;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS;   // yes i DO mean win32 here

import com.mypackage.ISilencer;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class Silencer implements ISilencer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Silencer.class);

    @Override
    public void silence() {
        // removes the annoying browser clicking sound!
        try {
            OS.CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(OS.FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS, OS.SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS, true);
        } catch (Throwable e1) {
            // I am just catching any exceptions that may come off this one since it is using restricted API so that if in any case it fail well it will just click.
            LOGGER.error("Caught exception while setting FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS.");
        }
    }
}
```

Since the BrowserSilencer is marked as `@Creatable` you can simply inject it into your class and call the `silence()` method

If it's not clear how to create and extension-point I can show that in a subsequent post.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Silence Windows SWT.browser widget from making awful clicks. 
// For windows 32 and 64 bit SWT applications. 
// Uses reflection to call OS.CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(OS.FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS, OS.SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS, true);
// Without importing platform specific 
// #import org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS  
private void silenceWindowsExplorer() {
    try {
        Class<?> c = Class.forName("org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS");
        java.lang.reflect.Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled", Integer.TYPE, Integer.TYPE, Boolean.TYPE);
        method.invoke(null, new Object[] {21, 2, true});
    } catch (Throwable th)
    {
        // Might fail.. but probably will never do harm.
        th.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix (probably) same problem of navigation sound when using SWT Browser in Windows (using IE) and I was able to find a solution w/o requiring code change.

I have found it's possible to change that by disabling to None the specific sound in Windows Control Panel. I have validated in Win 7 only:

> Control Panel => Sound => Sounds => Windows Explorer => Start Navigation
>   FROM: Windows Navigation Start.wav
>   TO: NONE

I hope this helps anyone who is looking for a non-code solution.

Comment: This is an irrelevant answer as this won't work for a software shipped to a client's machine